# Getting "'function' object is not iterable" while trying to make a bar plot

Tags: pandas

Note: Not sure how I can make the title more descriptive without messing it up. Please let me know if it's necessary

So I'm trying to make a bar plot of 5 countries from a list of 52 countries (y-axis), while showing number of data scientists from those countries on the bar (x-axis)

```
Countop = df_demog_ds['Country'].value_counts()
Counval = []
Counindex = []
for index, val in Countop.iteritems():
  Counindex.append(index)
  Counval.append(val)
print(Counindex[0:5])  

from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
fcounval = Counval[0:5]
fcounindex = Counindex[0:5]
barc = np.arange(5)
fig5, ax5 = plt.subplots
plt.bar(barc, fcounval)
plt.xticks(barc, fcounindex)
plt.show()
```

fcounval and fcounindex select the first 5 elements from Counval and Counindex. All 4 are lists

What I might be doing wrong here?

Link to the dataset - https://www7.zippyshare.com/v/IhcLQsKZ/file.html

Comment: `plt.subplots()`, you missed the parentheses

Comment: @Lambda Well, I feel stupid now. Thanks for the tip.